# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Wifi adapter not found

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, iwlwifi

I have a Lenovo P14s Gen2. I have dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. In the last weeks I only used Ubuntu, so I did not boot in Windows in a long time.

Until today, I was able to connect to the internet using both the ethernet cable and the wifi adapter. However, this morning I was faced with the error "No Wifi adapter found".

1. First, I tried disabling the fast boot in windows, which did not help.
2. Then, I tried to load the drivers in Ubuntu again using `sudo modeprobe -r iwlwifi` and `sudo modeprobe iwlwifi` which also made no difference.
3. Next, I followed the instructions here about [using the Ubuntu ISO to install drivers](https://www.fosslinux.com/43345/fix-the-no-wi-fi-adapter-found-error-on-ubuntu.htm). This was not successful since after mounting the ISO as CDRom it was not detected as an additional driver.

It seems like there is an error at boot time. These are the error messages afer `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[    2.818443] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.835893] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.835909] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.836304] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.838054] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.838069] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    2.838308] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.930861] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    3.085547] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[    3.185795] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    3.185797] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.185800] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[    3.185911] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.185912] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[    3.185912] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode
[    3.185913] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[    3.185914] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x002002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    3.185915] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    3.185916] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004D9BDC | branchlink2
[    3.185916] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004CFB22 | interruptlink1
[    3.185916] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004CFB22 | interruptlink2
[    3.185917] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004D8896 | data1
[    3.185917] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000010 | data2
[    3.185918] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[    3.185918] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    3.185919] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00011E5F | tsf low
[    3.185919] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    3.185920] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    3.185920] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00023956 | time gp2
[    3.185921] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    3.185921] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000003B | uCode version major
[    3.185922] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x601F3A66 | uCode version minor
[    3.185922] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000420 | hw version
[    3.185923] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x18489002 | board version
[    3.185923] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x8006FC03 | hcmd
[    3.185924] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    3.185924] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x20000000 | isr1
[    3.185924] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[    3.185925] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    3.185925] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    3.185926] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    3.185926] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x004D8896 | wait_event
[    3.185927] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    3.185927] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[    3.185928] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    3.185928] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    3.185928] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    3.185929] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    3.185929] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[    3.185977] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.185978] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    3.185978] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x201000B6 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    3.185979] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    3.185979] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x8045D8DE | umac branchlink2
[    3.185980] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x804878E0 | umac interruptlink1
[    3.185981] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    3.185981] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000006 | umac data1
[    3.185981] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[    3.185982] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[    3.185982] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000003B | umac major
[    3.185983] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x601F3A66 | umac minor
[    3.185983] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0002394E | frame pointer
[    3.185984] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0xC0886C30 | stack pointer
[    3.185984] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    3.185984] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    3.186002] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[    3.186002] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[    3.186012] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x000077B0 | IML/ROM data1
[    3.186026] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    3.186042] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    3.186045] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    3.186048] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x80440000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    3.186051] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00040090 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    3.186054] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    3.186057] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    3.186059] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    3.186062] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    3.186065] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    3.186068] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.186073] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.186078] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    3.186083] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    3.963756] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

4. I also tried doing a kernel update. No improvement either.

It seems like it tries to load three .ucode modules  `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-60.ucode`,  `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-61.ucode` and `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode` which do not exist. In `/lib/firmware` I only have iwlwifi versions 59 and 63, but not 60, 61, 62.

I am out of ideas, so any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` so the system does not throw `Timeout waiting for PNVM load!` anymore. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this personally by doing the following:

1. run `ip link` to get the interface you need (mine was wlp9s0 for reference)
2. then run `ip link <interface> up` to see if your interface is up (in my case mine was DOWN)
3. if down, run `ip link set dev <interface> up`

After a lot of messing around with this issue this finally fixed it for me, hope someone else can find it useful